# height of child related to parent width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have grid like this and my sidebar take 4 of 12 col near to 33.3% and my sidebar is parent element

```
$susy: (
        columns   : 12,
        gutters    : 1/1.618033989/1.618033989/1.618033989,
        math         : fluid,
        output        : float,
        gutter-position        : inside,
);
@include border-box-sizing;

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
 @include span(4);
}
```

and I have div tag in my side bar and width of child is 100% of parent, now I want height of child be width of parent*number

I have tried some thing like this

```
 width: 33.3333vw;
 height:20.601112354vw;
```

but that work when we are out of grid when there is no parent element
and I have tried this

```
#container {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
}
#dummy {
margin-top: 75%; /* 4:3 aspect ratio */
}

#element {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: silver /* show me! */
}
```

but there is many bugs in this method like you put 2 or more div tag in child and working with this should be full of tricks

I want some method that simply get width of parent and multiply that and make that height of child element.so when we resizing browser when width of parent get change -> height of child get change

Comment: post your html please

Comment: <div class="sidebar"><div class="child" style="width:100%;height:?"></div></div>  I want height of child = width of sidebar * number  and it should be percentage .

Answer (score 0):

```
var width = $('.child').width();
    var parentWidth = $('.sidebar').width();
    var ratio = parentWidth/1.618033989;
    $(".child").height(ratio);



$( window ).resize(function() {
    var width = $('.child').width();
    var parentWidth = $('.sidebar').width();
    var ratio = parentWidth/1.618033989;
    $(".child").height(ratio);
```